# How to "reduce typing to create C++ types" with Uniform Initializers?

Tags: initialization, c++11, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

I have played a lot the new *Uniform Initialization* with `{}`. Like this:

```
vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
map<int,string> getMap() {
    return { {1,"hello"}, {2,"you"} };
}
```

It is undisputed that this initialization may change we program C++.
But I wonder if I missed some of the **magic possibilities** when reading *Alfonses's* question in the [Herb Sutter FAQs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Herb-Sutter-C-Questions-and-Answers).

> Alfonse: Uniform initialization (the use of {} to call constructors when the type being constructed can be deduced) has the potential to radically reduce the quantity of typing necessary to create C++ types. It's the kind of thing, like lambdas, that will change how people write C++ code. [...]

Can someone give me an example of what *Alfonse* exactly envisions here?

Comment: what do you refer to by "side-statement"? Do you mean the part of the quote that appears in parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry, I shortend the quote after I wrote the last sentence. The section I quoted actually *is* the side-statement. His question was about the MSVC compiler. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume he means that

```cpp
std::vector<int> x{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::map<int, std::string> y{{1, "hello"}, {2, "you"}};
```

is significantly less typing than

```cpp
std::vector<int> x;
x.push_back(1);
x.push_back(2);
x.push_back(3);
x.push_back(4);
std::map<int, std::string> y;
y.emplace(1, "hello");
y.emplace(2, "you");
```

Comment: Hmmm, that is your interpretation of "to create C++ types"? Ok, I did not make that connection. I wonder if he may be thinking of even other things.

Comment: @towi : I assumed it was a non-native English speaker's way of saying "creating/instantiating objects". I could be wrong, but I can't think of what else he may have meant.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you discount the possibility that this was a simple mistake? That is, he wrote "create C++ types" when he meant "create C++ object". It seems strange that one wouldn't immediately think, "Oh, he meant 'object' but wrote the wrong thing."